# High Score Unity3D using PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have being trying to make a best time high score system using PlayerPrefs, I have looked at so many resources but am unsure what I am doing wrong. Bellow is my script containing my best time high score attempt, I have commented everything that I am trying to do with my script and what needs to be done or what I think may not be working.

All areas I am unsure about I have marked TODO: Not sure if I have done this correct.

For the method:

- `public bool hasBestTime()`: I need to check if I have a best time stored as a highscore
- `float GetBestTime()`: I need to get the current high score (best time) and return the current high score
- `public void PlayerWin()`: I need to read the read and store the high score (best time)

  ```
  using UnityEngine;

  using System.Collections;

  public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public static readonly string OUT_OF_FUEL_MESSAGE = "Out of fuel!";
      public static readonly string WIN_MESSAGE = "Goal collect! You win!";

      public static GameController Instance { get; private set; }

      private bool gameOver = false; //A flag to store when the game is over
      private int goalsRemaining = 0; //the number of goals that are remaining in the level
      private float gameTime = 0; //the time (in seconds) that the player has been playing the level

      void Awake()
      {
          UIController.LoadUI();
          Instance = this;
      }

      void OnDestroy()
      {
          Instance = null;
      }

      void Start()
      {

      }

      void Update()
      {
          if (!gameOver)
          {
              gameTime += Time.deltaTime;
          }

          UIController.SetTime(gameTime);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Check if the game is over
      /// </summary>
      public bool isGameOver
      {
          get
          {
              return gameOver;
          }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Check if we have a best time stored as a highscore
      /// </summary>
      public bool hasBestTime
      {
          get
          {
              if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Best Time"))
              {
                  return true;
              }
              return false; //TODO: Not sure if I am doing this correct
          }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Get the current highscore
      /// </summary>
      /// <returns>The current highscore</returns>
      float GetBestTime()
      {
          //time = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best Time");
          return gameTime; //TODO: Not sure if I am doing this correct
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Notify the game controller that the player has won the level
      /// </summary>
      public void PlayerWin()
      {
          gameOver = true;

          //Update the highscore
          float bestTime = 0;
          bool isNewHighscore = false;

          if (gameTime < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best Time"))
          {
              PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Best Time", gameTime);
          }
          //TODO: Not sure if I have done this correct trying to complete the code to read and store the highscore

          //Pop up the win message
          UIController.GameOver(WIN_MESSAGE, gameTime, bestTime, isNewHighscore);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Notify the game controller that the player has run out of fuel and lost the level
      /// </summary>
      public void PlayerOutOfFuel()
      {
          gameOver = true;
          if (hasBestTime)
          {
              UIController.GameOver(OUT_OF_FUEL_MESSAGE, gameTime, GetBestTime(), false);
          }
          else
          {
              UIController.GameOver(OUT_OF_FUEL_MESSAGE);
          }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Notify the game controller that the player has collected a goal
      /// </summary>
      public static void PlayerCollectGoal()
      {
          Instance.goalsRemaining--;
          UIController.SetRemaining(Instance.goalsRemaining);

          if (Instance.goalsRemaining == 0)
          {
              Instance.PlayerWin();
          }
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Notify the game controller that a goal has been spawned in the level
      /// </summary>
      public static void SpawnGoal()
      {
          Instance.goalsRemaining++;
          UIController.SetRemaining(Instance.goalsRemaining);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: You don't seem to set `bestTime` in `PlayerWin()`, it would be always zero. Other than that, it seems fine.

Comment: @Laykker I am asking how to use PlayerPrefs to determine if I there is currently a best time, to store the best time and compare my gameTime to the best time (high score) and if my gameTime is better then the best time update the best time to be my gameTime

Comment: Take a look : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/672869/player-prefs-to-store-high-scores.html

Comment: @Catwood yeah it is always 0. How do I set a best time?

Comment: `GetBestTime()` would work, you almost had it, but you commented out the line that would work.

Comment: @Laykker I have already looked at that answer I am a little unsure how to apply it to my script because my script is time not a score, so i need to check if there is an existing high score first otherwise my best time will remain as 0 seconds.

Comment: @Catwood it didn't work that's why I commented it out

Comment: This seems to be more a logic problem rather than a coding problem. PlayerPrefs are easy to work with, i am a little unsure what you need to happen.

Comment: best time is set at 0 `float bestTime = 0;` but never change. After you check if gametime < best time, try : ` bestTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best Time");`

Comment: @Laykker Thank you that works, but the only problem now is if I don't get a best time on my current run it will display my best time as 0. If I do get a best score it will display it as the current time.

Comment: if it's display 0 when you dont get a best time on your current run, that means you put your getFloat in your brackets. It displays 0 because bestTime = 0 and it's never change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void PlayerWin()
    {
        gameOver = true;

        //Update the highscore
        float bestTime = 0;
        bool isNewHighscore = false;

        if (gameTime < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best Time"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Best Time", gameTime);
        }
        //TODO: Not sure if I have done this correct trying to complete the code to read and store the highscore

        bestTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Best Time"); // ADD THIS LINE HERE

        //Pop up the win message
        UIController.GameOver(WIN_MESSAGE, gameTime, bestTime, isNewHighscore);
    }
```

Set you bestTime after you check if the actual time is a highscore, but before you display it.